# SQL Server ORDER BY Multiple values in case statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I am trying to do an order by with several different columns. The first column has several conditions.

The base order was something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table T
ORDER BY T.A, T.B, T.C
```

Most of the time column A is an int. Sometimes A is an int with a letter appended at the end. I want the order by to be my the number portion. I was able to achieve that by modifying the query to the following which has been working for months now.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table T
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(a.[HUDLine]) = 0 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(T.A,1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',T.A - 1) AS INT)
ELSE CAST (T.A AS INT) end
, T.B, T.C
```

Recently a new requirement came up which allows the value of "OFFLINE" to exist in column A.

I want to modify the ORDER BY to keep the same logic as before with the exception of all records with "OFFLINE" are at the end.

Answer (score 1):

First, I am very sorry about your requirements, it makes absolutely no sense that bizzarely mixed values are being stored in a varchar column.

Second try this

```
CASE WHEN a.[HUDLine] = 'OFFLINE' 
THEN 2147483647 --This is the maximum signed int value
ELSE 
    (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(a.[HUDLine]) = 0 
     THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(T.A,1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',T.A - 1) AS INT) 
     ELSE CAST (T.A AS INT) 
     END) 
 END
```

Show that to whoever is in charge of your datamodel, and politely ask them store meanigful numeric data in a numeric column.